# Read content of a file into filemaker

Tags: filemaker

I am looking for a way to read the content of a file into a variable to later on use it in FileMaker. I have done this manually by creating a new table field and add the file into the database as record and then use import record to save it as a field. However, I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of file? A text file, where the contents of the text are what you want the value of a variable to be?

Comment: Yes, a text file where the contents of the text is the value of a variable

Comment: If you import it as tab delimited data, you could get the text into a field, then use that to create a variable.

Comment: And how would you import the file as a tab delimited data? I tried the script step insert file but it does not insert the file; it inserted the name instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a plugin such as BBox, BaseElements or Monkeybread will let you read the contents of a file either using native scripts (Monkeybread or Baseelements) or via second language: Ruby, JS, etc. (bbox)

Baseelements example: 
https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207324907-BE-ReadTextFromFile

Answer (score 0):

You can use the’Insert from URL’ function to insert the file into a text or container field. Use a container field if you have extended characters in the file to preserve the encoding. Afterwards you can pull the contents out into a variable, if you need.

Comment: I tried Insert from URL and it keeps giving me error saying missing records so I am not sure why. I did use a container field when I tried using Insert from URL

Comment: So I re-ran the script and it gave me connection failed